# FaceBook Connect Login Button Not Appearing In FireFox

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, master-pages

I am working on a project for a client where they want to allow the visitors to the site sign-up using their FaceBook account.

I have used the FaceBook connect API for handling this. I have a top-menu item user-control that is in a masterpage. The FaceBook connect log-in control is appearing fine in IE8 and Chrome. However, it is not appearing in FireFox at all.

You can see this in action/or not depending on your browser at http://dev.booncentral.com/

**Some MasterPage FB Code:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

**End of the MasterPage:**

```
 <script type="text/jscript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/jscript">
        FB.init({ appId: '<% = Evolution.Utils.AppSettings.GetAppSetting("FacebookApiKey") %>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function (response) {
            if (response.session) {
            } else {
            }
        });
    </script></body>
```

**UserControl:**

```
 <fb:login-button perms="publish_stream,email,user_birthday" onlogin="window.location.reload()"
            autologoutlink="true" width="200"></fb:login-button>
```

Has anyone come across this or have any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FaceBook code above was fine.

It turned out that there was a problem where a developer tried to convert a 64bit integer to 32bit int elsewhere in the code.